# is it possible to make a layer dim(cocos2dx)

Tags: cocos2d-x

I hope to pop up a new layer and make all layers under the layer become dim.

such as score board, dialog panel, I hope they can be clearer.

Is it possible?

Your comment welcome

Comment: you can set z order of your pop-up layer as well as you can set opacity of all other layers.I think, this way you might achieve

Comment: To achieve what you want, You have to use one black image.And You have to put that before any layer and then make is semi transparent using opacity of that. Than add you scorecard layer on that. Along that you have to disable all the button on other layer. For example check last screenshot of my game:https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bounceme!/id692676722?mt=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I did this for a pause layer:

```
CCLayerColor *bgLayer = CCLayerColor::create(ccc4(0,0,0,170));
this->addChild(bgLayer);

//Add other pause menu elements (Title, Resume button, quit button, etc.)
```

I added this inside of a button click event, and the entire screen becomes dim. Just make sure this layer is on top of your other layers.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently for a game, I used a Scale9Sprite for a dialog box, and used a LayerColor to dim everything else.

You need to add the LayerColor at the lowest z index as a child to your YourDialogBoxClassName (itself needs to inherit from Layer), I added the LayerColor instance to z index 0 for me.

Also, if you want to add actions, such as ScaleTo, to provide a poping effect, make sure to override setScaleX and setScaleY to give the background LayerColor a constant scale of 1.0f. You may also want to do this to the methods setRotationX and setRotationY if you add a slight rotation to your dialog.

You will also probably want to disable all touches to the background layer, I did this by overriding the methods onEnter and onExit:

```
void YourDialogBoxClassName::onEnter() {
    Director::getInstance()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, Menu::HANDLER_PRIORITY, true);
    Layer::onEnter();
}

void YourDialogBoxClassName::onExit() {
    Director::getInstance()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    Layer::onExit();
}
```

Then you will need in YourDialogBoxClassName:

```
bool YourDialogBoxClassName::ccTouchBegan(Touch * touch, Event * event ) {
    //Consumes the touch
    return true; 
}
```

Because you added the background to the lower z index, the touches will still register for menu items in your main dialog sprite (or whatever it is you are showing).